# Executing binary files using exec* in c

Tags: c, shell, exec

I am creating a toy shell. I want to execute a binary file which is either located in the PATH variable or the current directory. This is what I am doing to achieve it:

```
execl(filePath," -e ",com.arguments,NULL);  //e.g of filePath: /home/dino/programs/mywrapper
```

Now it works fine for some executables like `which` command. But for commands like `tar`, a whole bunch of error throws up.

Basically all I want is the `execl` to execute the executable mentioned in `filePath` in my shell. How do I do it?

**EDIT:**
`com.arguments` is the arguments list. For example in `which bash`, `bash` becomes my argument. In `tar -zvcf bazinga.tar.gz bazinga/`, `-zvcf bazinga.tar.gz bazinga/` becomes my arguments etc.

Comment: Are you calling `fork()` before calling `execl()`?

Comment: yes, I am calling fork()

Comment: Remember that the arguments you pass to the program you `exec` is what becomes `argv` in that program. So the first argument (what will be `argv[0]`) should be the program name.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to answer this question if you told us _which_ errors you get, and perhaps even prepared a _minimal, working example that still shows the problem_?

Comment: you mean something like execl(com.command,filePath," -e ", com.arguments, NULL) ?

Comment: If `com.arguments` is the arguments list, you probably want to use `execv` instead of `execl`.

Answer (score 0):

From [`execl`'s documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)

```
 The first argument, by convention, should point to the
filename associated with the file being executed.
```